# how do i setup linux proxy

Tags: linux, networking, proxy

I know this is a stupid question, but how in the world is the proxy set up in Linux. The network I'm trying to connect to is a proxy network and i point my settings to 192.168.49.1:8282. Now i cant seem to find manual proxy settings in Kali Linux but i think that's because of the software that Kali uses at default. When i used Linux mint it worked fine in web browsers and other apps work but the terminal programs such as apt and ping don't like to use the http_proxy environment variable. should I be using software such as proxychains and prefix every command with "proxychains". I've found various articles that include creating files in /etc/profile.d/ containing "http_proxy=http://192.168.49.1:8282" or using the export command to set "http_proxy", or adding the "http_proxy" variables to /etc/environment. To be clear iv used the https_proxy as well in all of the examples given. what could i try next.

Comment: I'm not good at explaining exactly what I mean so please feel free to request additional info

Comment: I assume the file you created in `/etc/profile.d` contains `export http_proxy=.....` etc not just `http_proxy=.....` AND that the file you created is executable for all users? have you read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/724725/how-to-set-up-system-wide-proxy-in-kali-linux)

Comment: the reason I'm kind of desperate to figure this out is that we don't own a WIFI network at the house so I tend to max out my hotspot every month for everyday tasks. I'm using a great app called Netshare that uses creates a wifi direct network and then uses a proxy to forward that traffic on the wifi-direct network to the internet, therefore bypassing hotspot bandwidth problems.

Comment: @JaromandaX yes i believe i completed the first part correctly, but quite confident I didnt mess with permissions.

Comment: well, you could show the content of the file you created, and `ls -l /etc/profile.d/the-file-you-created` then we'll see if you did it right

Comment: -rwxr-xr-x 1 logan root 43 Jan 30 10:02 /etc/profile.d/http_proxy.sh is the output of ls -l

Comment: export http_proxy=http://192.168.49.1:8282 is the contents of the file. should this file run when sourced with "source http_proxy.sh"

Comment: should these settings be exported in bash.rc

Comment: Please note that SE sites aren't discussion boards. Have a look at the [Help](https://superuser.com/help) to learn how these sites work. Instead of answering in comments you should [edit] your question to clarify it and add more information.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this script "Anonsurf" by following the links provided - https://github.com/Und3rf10w/kali-anonsurf for Linux or https://github.com/ultrafunkamsterdam/AnonSurf for windows, it automatically redirects your traffic through tor.. For more information, read the documentation provided on github.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Steven.kamanga thanks for your reply. i got that working this evening but what it does is automates tor, which is great. but all I'm wanting to do is create a simple tcp tunnel from all local traffic on port 80 to "192.168.49.1:8282" which is the port that my ap is listening on for traffic. maybe anonsurf will do that and im just desperately dense

Comment: a little update iv been using proxychains and its working quite well for the most part although definitely less than ideal. still open for suggestions though